# Sumsung S Planner and Google Calendar issues

Tags: android-intent, calendar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am having issues with a app that works fine on all the ICS phones i have tested but not Samsung with S Planner
i'm using a intent of action pick to pick a event. The problem that when is call s planner is crashes on return. I decided to install standard Google Calendar on the phone as this should solve my issue. 
here is the code

```
    public static String ANDROID_CALENDAR_AUTHORITY_1_0 = "calendar";
    public static String ANDROID_CALENDAR_AUTHORITY_2_0 = "com.android.calendar";
    public static String ANDROID_CALENDAR_PROVIDER_PATH_CALENDARS = "calendars";
    public static String ANDROID_CALENDAR_PROVIDER_PATH_EVENTS = "events";

    selected_google_calendar_id = getCallPlanCalendar();
    Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
    .scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT) 
    .authority( CalendarProviderConstants. ANDROID_CALENDAR_AUTHORITY_2_0)
    .appendPath(CalendarProviderConstants.ANDROID_CALENDAR_PROVIDER_PATH_EVENTS).build();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, uri);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CALENDAR_ID, selected_google_calendar_id);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

The issue is i can not get code to open the Google Calendar app even is i remove s planner. If its removed it crashs Is there a way to change the default app to open or has sumsung hacked it so only s planner will open?